# Is it appropriate to flag a question for moderator intervention to have it protected?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, first-post-review, protected-questions, moderator-intervention

This morning I was going through the "First Posts" queue and noticed a new answer to [this question on ignored `.gitignore` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working). This question has many answers and new ones seem to get added periodically. It's a "Famous Question" with over 500k views. IMO, this question should be protected, because there are many answers being frequently added (and in my opinion, many of the answers are low quality from new users and some are duplicates of other answers). However, I don't have the necessary 15k rep to mark it as protected. I was thinking about flagging the question for moderator intervention, asking a moderator to mark the question as protected in the comments when flagging it.

I know that from the criteria of what questions should be protected, that protecting a question is meant to prevent spam comments like "Me too!" and "Thanks!". I see very few such comments. However, according to [Jeff Atwood's canonical blog post on protected questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/07/new-protected-question-status/): *"if you see a question that is attracting a lot of drive-by noise answers, please flag it for moderator attention. We’ll turn on protection."*

I'm a little unsure as on whether or not I should flag the question for moderator attention. I searched and found no other questions on this topic. It feels somewhat inappropriate to me to ask a mod to intervene like this. It also seems like the question has existed for so long already, that if it should be protected, then it would have been marked as such some time ago. I also think that I might just be overthinking this whole matter. :-P

Comment: All you need is a privileged user. Maybe post a message in the SOCVR room?

Comment: Protection only does so much.

Comment: If newly added answers are low quality, a down vote will help to signal a post hasn't value. The latest answers I checked had no votes at all. A side effect of your down vote is enabling the delete option for 20K-ers.

Answer (score 7):

So as noted in comments, protection can only do so much.  It is effectively saying, "So many people are adding poor answers to this *often*, and it's making moderation efforts of this question tough."

I would actually argue here that this question should be locked and prevent new answers.  That's a mod-only lock which sends the clear message why a post like this is locked - no new information is capable of being contributed to this sort of problem.

I'd say flagging for attention would be fine in this context.  Have the mod reverse this from a standard post protection to a post lock removing the ability to add new answers.

Comment: For the most part I agree with this answer, but I disagree that the question should be locked because IMO it’s reasonable to assume that what’s there right now won’t work in all cases and somebody else can contribute new legit answers, especially as Git evolves.

Comment: @entpnerd:  I don't disagree, but Git is highly unlikely to suddenly and unexpectedly change behavior in how its ignore structure works.  If *any* Git question were safe to lock, this would be one of them.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered difficulties as a moderator locking questions to protect them from low quality answers or to preserve historical value. It's a double edged sword, as it prevents the question and answers being voted on.

As [rene says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379463/is-it-appropriate-to-flag-a-question-for-moderator-intervention-to-have-it-prote?cb=1#comment665699_379463) protection does only so much, there's still many users able to post. This is where we need curators of the site watching these posts and downvoting and flagging bad answers. There's also automatic flags raised when questions get a lot of answers and the mods will check the latest answers.

There's no harm in raising a mod flag to have questions locked, a community consensus, by asking on Meta is also a good idea.